# Got local host name, working on windows, but not in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, getaddrinfo

I wrote a program to get local host name. if it is not obvious, I mean to get the host name of the local machine similar to `gethostname` method, not to get the string `localhost`

I'm using `getaddrinfo` with `NULL` for host name and then call to `getnameinfo` with the first address.

It works perfectly on windows machines, and giving me the canonical host name, but in Linux it failed to give me the local host name and gives me `::` for IPv6 or `0.0.0.0` for IPv4.

Note that I'm using `AI_PASSIVE` flag in `getaddrinfo`, means it gives me no more than two addresses.

In the `getnameinfo` if I use the `NI_NAMEREQD` it fail.

I'm doing so because I have a server, sometimes I want to listen to all interfaces and sometimes to a specific interface, I'm already have the `addrinfo` and I just want to get the hostname from it if possible.

How can I make it work on Linux? 
did I missed anything?

Thanks for any help.

Here is my code: (cross platform, windows and Linux, just copy & past)
You can compile and run on both and see the difference.

```
#include <iostream> 

#ifdef WIN32

#ifdef UNICODE
#undef UNICODE /* don't want Unicode, to keep code compatibility */
#endif

#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
class CWSAInitializer{
public:
    CWSAInitializer(){
        WSADATA data;
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&data);
    }
    ~CWSAInitializer(){
        WSACleanup();
    }
}autoInit;

#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#endif

const char* get_hostname(struct addrinfo* info, char buff[], int buff_len)
{
    int addrlen = (int)info->ai_addrlen;
    int res = getnameinfo(info->ai_addr, addrlen, buff, buff_len, NULL, 0, 0);
    if(res){
        return NULL;
    }
    return buff;
}

int main () 
{
    char temp[100];
    addrinfo *ai,hints;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV;
    hints.ai_flags |= AI_PASSIVE;

    int res = getaddrinfo(NULL, "0", &hints, &ai); 
    if(res){
        std::cerr<<gai_strerror(res)<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout<< get_hostname(ai,temp,100)<<std::endl;
    freeaddrinfo(ai);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

1. The server should accept client from other machines as well, so it can't report listening on `::` or `0.0.0.0`.
2. I know I can patch it like this:

`if(std::string("::") == hostname || std::string("0.0.0.0") == hostname) 
       gethostname(hostname,100)`

3. I don't want to get `localhost` as result, unless the address is `127.0.0.1` or `::1`.

Comment: If you ONLY want the local host name, why don't you use INADDR_LOOPBACK?

Comment: I don't want the localhost interface. the server is listenning outside, I want to know which **hostname** I'm currently listenning. If client would try to connect to :: or to 0.0.0.0 it won't connect.

Answer (score 1):

`getaddrinfo()` returns the head of list of `struct addrinfo` nodes.

Travers this list using `struct addrinfo`'s a member `ai_next` to find the addresses of all interfaces of the machine.

To receive anything else but wildcard addresses do **not** specify the `AI_PASSIVE` flag in the hints passed.

---

**Update on the various names given to a machine and/or its interfaces' addresses:**

1. The host's name ("*hostname*") as returend by `gethostname()` is an attribute to the host. It is **configured on the host** and not held in any external database. This host name **per definition is not linked** to any of the names the possible interfaces' addresses resolve to. The host name **might** however be **configured** to match the name that **one** of the addresses (of the interfaces of the machine) resolves to.
2. There might be more then one interface provided by a machine. Each of these interfaces' address should resolves to a different name, which in turn could also all differ from the name returned by `gethostname()` (see 1. above). This applies to all types of interfaces including IPv4 and IPv6. There also it the virtual wildcard-address (`0.0.0.0`for IPv4) which allows programs to bind to and listen on **all** interfaces (IPv4 typed here) a machine provides. The wildcard-adresse has **no** name.

The conclusion from 1. and 2. is: **There is no name** "*... like [returned by] gethostname() but canonical.*"!

Comment: On both windows and Linux I have two addresses in the list: one gives me `::` the other `0.0.0.0` I used `AI_PASSIVE` deliberately. I don't want to get `localhost` I want to get the canonical host name.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, if I want it to work on Linux, if I'm listening on ANY interface (gave NULL to 1st `getaddrinfo` param), I need to use `gethostname`, or to use another `getaddrinfo` without the `AI_PASSIVE` flag. maybe really there is no other way.

Comment: It is not good, it gives me `localhost` as name. I want **THE** machine name. like `gethostname` but canonical.

Comment: that doesn't exist, does it?  each address has its own name and a single machine can have many network cards and many addresses.